# Satan does not "work" On Yom Kippur

Tags: talmud-gemara, yom-kippur, rishonim, satan

The Gemara in Nedarim 32B states;

> הַשָּׂטָן בְּחוּשְׁבָּנֵיהּ תְּלָת מְאָה וְשִׁיתִּין וְאַרְבְּעָה

> The letters of the term the Satan [haSatan] in numerical value is 364, which equals the number of days of the year, except for Yom Kippur, during which he has no power.

The English Translation (from Sefaria) seems to be based on the Ran;

> השטן בחושבנא תלת מאה ושיתין וארבע הוו - וימות החמה שס''ה א''כ איכא חד יומא דלית ליה רשותא למשטן דהיינו יוה''כ:

My question is that 365 days is in a solar year while Yom Kippur is based on the lunar year. This means that aside from a lunar leap year, there will be 2 Yom Kippur days within 365 days of each other. It seems incongruent to work off of the solar number for the total value and the solar calendar for the "Day off".

Comment: In regards to the Ketores it says that there were 368 Portions / 365 for each sun day / 3 additional for Tom Kippur. Thus you see that there are other Jewish items that are based on the solar year. In actuality the Jewish year is interwined with the solar year and we have leap years to make this conversion accurate. At the end of the day the average Jewish lunar year is 365 days also.

Comment: The Ketores could be was only done every 365 days and/or the extra was put away as the brasia states every 60 to 70 years they used it for half. But we do see again that Yom kippur is mentioned and again the 365 days, but Yom Kippur comes every 354 days or every 384 days not 365.

Comment: However in a 19 year cycle of 7 additional Adars, the Jewish year averages to 365 days per year.

Comment: But if the Solar year starts in Tishrei (October) according to R' Elazar then there would be a number of Solar years with 2 Yom Kippurs, year 1 for example would have 2 Yom Kippurs

Comment: And some years would have no Yom Kippurs however at the end of the day that doesn't matter. What matters is that on a average year of 365 days, the Satan has no power on 1 day, which Chazal say is on Yom Kippur.

Comment: BTW solar year begins before Tishrei as creation started 6 days prior. Thus even according to your example there will not be two Yom Kippurs in year 1.

Comment: True, assuming that the lunar year in regards to Chagim started on Day 6 instead of when the moon was created. We do say Hayom Haras Olam on Rosh Hashana meaning 1 Tishrei not when the moon was created.

Comment: See yaros divash drush vav who answers this question. He says nun and mem are interchangable. Says kabbala stuff there which i didn't understand.

Comment: Amazing piece.  Thank you!!